# Negative Half of Sine Wave Passes Through Off MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, switching

I'm trying to design a MOSFET based switch which allows a sinewave through, however I noticed that when I was simulating it in LTSpice, whenever I try to turn off the FET the negative half of the sinewave still passes through.

Why is this and how do I prevent this from happening?

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that FETs contain an internal body diode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the source and body of your MOSFET are internally connected together. When you apply a negative voltage to the drain you will forward-bias the internal PN junction between the MOSFET body (p-type) and the drain (n-type).

You might want to just use an analog switch that is designed for this purpose rather than build your own.